# DataGrid shows strange Checkboxes below heading

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

i've got a problem displaying a `datagrid` using dojo.
Populating the grid with data provided by a `ItemFileReadStore` works fine. But the result looks like this:

[image: The Datagrid displays two Checkboxes, and i don't know why]

The two `checkboxes` below the Grid-Headings are not supposed to be there. I've already experimented with the DataGrid's property `rowSelector` but i oviously wasn't successful.

I've created the `DataGrid` programmatically. This is the sourcecode:

```
    var oStore = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({
       data:{
          identifier: 'catID',
             items: [
                {catID: '3', duration: '1,5'},
                {catID: '4', duration: '2,0'},
                {catID: '9', duration: '1,0'},
                {catID: '7', duration: '2,0'}
             ]  
          }
       });

       var oGrid = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({
          store: oStore,
          query:{ catID:'*'},
          autoHeight: 5,
          structure:[
             {name: 'KatalogID', field: 'catID', width: 'auto'},
             {name: 'Dauer', field: 'duration', width: 'auto'}
          ]
       }, dojo.create('div', {'id':'oGrid'}));
       oGrid.startup();
```

Does anybody know, where these checkboxes come from and how they can be removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a possible Workaround, but this doesn't fix the problem:
Including the following css-code hides the `div`-container containing the unbeloved checkboxes.

```
    <style type="text/css">

       .dojoxGridView > .dijitCheckBox{
          display: none; 
       }

    </style>
```

Unfortunately, this involeves the `checkBoxes` that are generated by the `rowSelector`-option within the `DataGrid`-declaration. So if you dont need the rowSeletion-feature (at least by checkboxes), this works.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem many time and it is removed by including Grid.css and theme css. This can be remove by just playing with css.

Comment: Hey, unfortunately i've already included those 2 css files. Without them, the `DataGrid` would look nothing like in the picture but like a blown up table or something. If somebody has any other Ideas, it would be great, as i could use those Checkboxes on the right place in the future...